# Map header from Apache to servlet request attribut

Tags: apache, spring-mvc, tomcat, authentication

Not sure if this question should be here or on Server Fault, but here it is:

**Context**

I have a web application based on Spring which needs client SSL authentication to authenticate users.
Autentication is done via an [X509AuthenticationFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/x509/X509AuthenticationFilter.java#LC29), which needs a javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate as request attribute.

Our architecture is the following:

- A WAF handles the SSL handcheck (Behind the WAF, data are transmitted in HTTP, not in HTTPS anymore)
- It forwards the client certificate as a header (SSL_CLIENT_CERT) encoded in base64 to an Apache placed in front of a Tomcat (where my app is deployed)

**Problem**

I can't find how to map the header to the attribute. I know I could write a Spring filter to authenticate the user based on the header and not on the attribute, but I don"t want to modify the application if possible. I think it's possible to do it with a good configuration of Apache or Tomcat, but I can't find it.

I hope it's clear enough

Comment: I know it's unrelated to your question but if you feel you need enough security to use mutual auth SSL, you should probably use SSL everywhere. Including between the WAF and app server. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Is your WAF correctly sending the header to httpd? Is httpd correctly sending the header to Tomcat?